# Css to expanded asp:dropdown list [picture included]

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

Though it may sound silly and simple, somehow, I am having hard time applying css to expanded dropdownlist. You can see the below picture. All I want to do is remove that thick black border. How can I do this?

[image]

I am using `<asp:dropdownlist>`. I tried applying border: `0px and outline:0px` etc.. and many other things but none of the css get applied to the dropdown box when I click the dropdown to see the list of languages inside.

Comment: Could you please include the ASP code?

Comment: BlackPanic: I had tried that already, but, no luck!!

Comment: @un-lucky : Below is my tag and I bind the list on runtime from code behind <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguages" runat="server"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="lnkFre_ServerClick" AutoPostBack="true"
            DataTextField="Key" DataValueField="Value" >

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot apply css to the list built by control asp:dropdownlist.

This is because, the list is built and rendered by OS. Therefore, it is dynamic and default.